# What/where is the mint public key in genesis config source code?

Tags: validator

solana document says "Before starting any validators, one first needs to create a genesis config. The config references two public keys, a **mint** and a bootstrap validator. " [https://docs.solana.com/cluster/overview#:~:text=Before%20starting%20any,the%20mint%27s%20account](https://docs.solana.com/cluster/overview#:%7E:text=Before%20starting%20any,the%20mint%27s%20account).

where can I find mint pubkey in source code (I checked genesis::main.rs and sdk::genesis_config.rs, and not found)? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for some time. I found this

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/runtime/src/genesis_utils.rs#L167

This is used to create a new genesis config

This is what you are looking for

```
 GenesisConfigInfo {
        genesis_config,
        mint_keypair,
        voting_keypair,
        validator_pubkey: *validator_pubkey,
    }
```

Where `mint_keypair` and `validator_pubkey` are the mint and bootstrap validator respectively.